# MacBook Air - Upgrading from Mac OS X Lion to macOS Sierra

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook Air running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5. I wish to upgrade it to macOS Sierra, but it requires at-least OS X Mountain Lion 10.8 which is not available anymore in the App Store.

Is there any other way to update the OS?

Comment: It is available if you have used it before on your account.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out I can still download El Capitan so should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't specifically looking to run macOS Sierra, Apple recommends upgrading to macOS High Sierra.

You can find the instructions to download and install macOS Sierra here:

[How to download macOS Sierra](https://support.apple.com/HT208202)